# error in inner join function

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I currently have a table as (Sample snapshot):

```
Employee ID Old Value      New Value         Update Date

1           Analyst        non-employee     10/1/2012

1           non-employee   Senior Analyst   10/1/2012

2           Analyst        non-employee      9/1/2012

2           non-employee   Assistant Mgr.    9/1/2012

2           Assistant Mgr. non-employee     10/1/2015

2           non-employee   Manager          10/1/2015

3           Analyst        non-employee     10/1/2015

3           non-employee     Manager          10/1/2015

4           Analyst        non-employee      9/1/2012

4           non-employee   Senior Analyst    9/1/2012

4           Senior Analyst non-employee     10/1/2015

4           non-employee   Assistant Mgr.   10/1/2015

4           Assistant Mgr. non-employee     10/6/2015

4           non-employee   Manager          10/6/2015
```

From this table, I need to pick out those employee IDs that transitioned from analyst to manager directly,i.e. without becoming a assistant manager or senior analyst.

**Desired Result:**

```
Employee ID Old Value   New Value   Update Date

3           Analyst     Manager     10/1/2015
```

I ran the query below in access to get the desired result:

```
select t.id, t.oldvalue, tnext.newvalue, t.updatedate
from table t inner join
     table tnext
     on t.employeeid = tnext.employeeid and
        t.updatedate = tnext.updatedate and
        t.newvalue = 'non-employee' and
        tnext.oldvalue = 'non-employee'
where t.oldvalue = 'Analyst' and tnext.newvalue = 'Manager';
```

I get the error as Join expression not supported with `t.newvalue='non-employee'` portion of the query highlighted. I googled the issue but I am unable to figure out the problem. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In join condition, try changing

```
tnext.oldvalue = 'non-employee'
```

to

```
tnext.oldvalue = 'non-member'
```

I think that should solve your problem.

Comment: Apologies for the typo in the table. It should have been non-employee. Anytime a change happens, the status first changes to non-employee and then to the new status.

Comment: I just ran the same query against the same relation in a sqlite database and got the perfect result. What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using MS Access. Unfortunately, that's the only software I have with me currently.

Comment: Could you try shifting the expression `t.newvalue = 'non-employee' and tnext.oldvalue = 'non-employee'` from `join` condition to `where` clause. I was checking out msdn documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff197346.aspx#Anchor_0 and I don't think they allow that. Not sure though.

Comment: I did that. But in that case, Access prompts me to enter the details for all the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys... I think I figured out the problem. I had to write the query in the format that is "acceptable" to MS Access. 
I wrote this query and it worked:

SELECT a1.uid, a1.oldvalue, a2.newvalue, a1.updatedate

FROM Table1 AS a1 INNER JOIN

(Select Table1.uid, Table1.oldvalue, Table1.newvalue, Table1.updatedate FROM Table1 where Table1.oldvalue="Non-Employee" AND Table1.newvalue="Manager")  AS a2

ON (a1.updatedate = a2.updatedate) AND (a1.uid = a2.uid)

WHERE (((a1.oldvalue)="Analyst") AND ((a1.newvalue)="Non-Employee"));